# Dynamic SQL query which is based on current month

Tags: sql, dynamicquery

Below is a SQL Code which creates a table from the union of monthly data summaries:

```
-- Oct 2017

select distinct  a.device_id ,201710 as month_id,
case when group_descr in ('BASE') then 'Basic'
     when group_descr in ('VALUES') then 'Valuable'
     when group_descr in ('PREFERRENCE') then 'Preferr'
     else 'Other'
end as Class
from dbo.DEVICE_HIST a
where a.expired >= '2017-10-01' and a.EFFTV <'2017-10-31'

union

-- Nov 2017
select distinct  a.device_id ,201711 as month_id,
case when group_descr in ('BASE') then 'Basic'
     when group_descr in ('VALUES') then 'Valuable'
     when group_descr in ('PREFERRENCE') then 'Preferr'
     else 'Other'
end as Class
from dbo.DEVICE_HIST a
where a.expired >= '2017-11-01' and a.EFFTV <'2017-11-30'

union

-- Dec 2017
select distinct  a.device_id ,201712 as month_id,
case when group_descr in ('BASE') then 'Basic'
     when group_descr in ('VALUES') then 'Valuable'
     when group_descr in ('PREFERRENCE') then 'Preferr'
     else 'Other'
end as Class
from dbo.DEVICE_HIST a
where a.expired >= '2017-12-01' and a.EFFTV <'2017-12-31'

union

-- Jan 2018
select distinct  a.device_id ,201801 as month_id,
case when group_descr in ('BASE') then 'Basic'
     when group_descr in ('VALUES') then 'Valuable'
     when group_descr in ('PREFERRENCE') then 'Preferr'
     else 'Other'
end as Class
from dbo.DEVICE_HIST a
where a.expired >= '2018-01-01' and a.EFFTV <'2018-01-31'
```

This is to be run monthly and based on the current month, we need to take 3 months data from last month - 1, backward.
For example, if run in Feb it should take from Oct-Dec and if run in Mar it should take from Nov - Jan.
This will be based on the current month but can someone please help me to automate this?

Something which takes the current month and goes back - 1 and then from there further 3 months.
Though the date calculation is not that complex, how to make the query dynamically change based on current month?

Comment: Which version of SQL?  SQL Server 2016 has an EOMonth() function where as previous versions didn't

Comment: Which RDMS are you using?  You basically need to change all those hardcoded dates to use a function to take today's date, then find the first/ last day of the current month, then last month, etc.  But the syntax will depend on which database you are using.

Comment: Unrelated, but for performance it is better to use `UNION ALL`. Also, why do you use `IN` with only one value? `in ('BASE')` is identical to `= 'BASE'`.

Comment: What is the relationship between `a.expired` and `a.EFFTV`? Are both of them required?

Comment: The DB is PostGreSql and yes both the a.expired and a.EFFTV are needed.

Comment: You should tag your question properly. `sql` isn't a specific RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is SQL SERVER 2005+:

```
-- Oct 2017
select distinct  a.device_id
                ,CONCAT(CAST(YEAR(a.expired) AS varchar(4)),right('00'+CAST(MONTH(a.expired) AS nvarchar(2)), 2))  as month_id,
                case when group_descr in ('BASE') then 'Basic'
                     when group_descr in ('VALUES') then 'Valuable'
                     when group_descr in ('PREFERRENCE') then 'Preferr'
                     else 'Other'
                end as Class
from @test a
where CONVERT(date, a.expired) >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, convert(date, DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()))), 0)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but since it is accepted, maybe the question was wrong?

Comment: @PeterAbolins: yes i missed the where clause cause i didnt test on real data. Tried to create a test table and i am going to edit my answer

Comment: Well... the question specified that the range should be 3 months, but start from one month ago. So, you need to match `getdate() - 4 months` through to `getdate() - 1 month`. Also... `in` makes no sense if there is only one value.

Comment: the `in` may be there cause he wants the code ready for adding more values in future, but yes its is generally correct to use the = operator instead. the `getdate() - 4 months` may not be correct cause he could miss part of the considered month (e.g. if today is march 30 and he wants all december, he will miss days 1-29 )